# Can I use Ruby gems in my Rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

How would I use ruby gems in my rails app. I am having difficulty getting them to work, but I am sure I am just missing something simple here since I am new with rails.

For example I have the gems youtube_it and yahoo-music that I would like to be able to use in my rails app. Is this possible?

Comment: You should really describe what you tried and what you got. The genral answer to your general question is YES.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using Rails 3, just add them to your `Gemfile` and they'll be available to your app:

```
gem 'youtube_it'
gem 'yahoo-music'
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Dylan Markov sais, just add them to your gem file. Don't forget to bundle install after doing this. But some gems actually need to be installed into the app as well. You should check the documentation for the gem on how to do this.